# How to add Flaticons to my website using CDN link

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I have a simple html css js page that i wanna add some flaticons on it, i don't wanna download the icons on my laptop, for many reasons, anyway , i tried to add the icons via a cdn link, but nothing happened like i didn't add them at all.

CDN link:

```
<head>
<!--flaticon -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flat-ui/2.3.0/css/flat-ui.min.css" 
    integrity="sha512-6f7HT84a/AplPkpSRSKWqbseRTG4aRrhadjZezYQ0oVk/B+nm/US5KzQkyyOyh0Mn9cyDdChRdS9qaxJRHayww==" 
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

</head>
```

and this is the icon :

```
<div class="header-phone-icon">
    <i class="flaticon-phone-call "></i>
</div>
```

Sorry if that seems like a silly question bcz it's my first time using flaticons

Answer (score 0):

There is no icon called `flaticon-phone-call`

[You will find here a list of existing icons](http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/?utm_source=cdnjs&utm_medium=cdnjs_link&utm_campaign=cdnjs_library)

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flat-ui/2.3.0/css/flat-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="header-phone-icon">
    <i class="fui-user">hello world</i>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, that was helpful, can u plz tell me what to do if want to add the following icon: https://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/phone-call_46854

Comment: According to there official phone icons are not included, maybe you can try other icon libraries.

Comment: do you recommend any ones? i only know fontawesome and recently knew flaticons

Comment: fontawesome is good

Comment: ionicon is another great one. https://ionic.io/ionicons/